# How do i make about component show?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I can't navigate to the about component and another component only the Navigation page is showing

```
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About}></Route>
          <Route path="/price" exact component={Pricing}></Route>
          <Route path="/testimony" exact component={Testimonial}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div> 
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `Route` props no longer take `exact` and `component` props, they take a `path` and `element` props. Another difference you'll see is that you render the route's child component as JSX instead of passing a reference to the component.

The `Navbar` also needs to be rendered within the `Router` so it receives the routing context.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/price" element={<Pricing />} />
          <Route path="/testimony" element={<Testimonial />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-make-about-component-show]

See the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) for other changes and how to upgrade from v5 to v6.